# compactness and subspaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ be a topological space. Let $K \subset Y \subset T$. Let $Y$ have the subspace topology. Let $K$ be compact in $Y$. Is $K$ compact in $T$ ?

Well, for one hand, i think that if we think about $]0,1] \subset  ]0,2[ \subset \mathbb{R} $, we see that since $]0,1]$ is closed and bounded in $]0,2[$, is compact in $Y$. However $]0,1]$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$, since is not closed.

But, what fails in this "proof" ?  Let $\lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace_{\alpha \in A}$ be an open covering of $K$ with open sets of $X$. Let $V_{\alpha} = U_{\alpha} \cap Y$, which is an open set in Y with subspace topology. Since $K$ is compact in $Y$ by hypothesis, we have that $K \subset \cap_{i=1}^{n} V_{i}$. Then, considering $\lbrace U_{i}\rbrace_{i=1}^{n} \subset \lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace_{\alpha \in A}$, we have that $K$ is compact in X ???

Thanks for the attention :)  [and help]

Comment: $(0,1]$ is not compact. The subspace topology is the same as a subspace of $(0,2)$ or of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $]0,1]$ is closed and bounded subset of $]0,2[$. Why doesn't Heine-Borel imply this to be compact ? Or isn't $]0,1]$ closed in subspace topology ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Would you argue that $(0,2)$ is compact, since it is bounded and closed in $(0,2)$? It isn't, because $(0,2)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ which is not compact.

Comment: I know, you're absolutely right :) but, what is the condition of Heine-Borel that fails here ?

Comment: H-B is a Theorem about the spaces $\Bbb R^n$, not about spaces homeomorphic to a $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @thetruth The topology on a metrizable space can always be defined by a *bounded* metric: just define $e(x,y)=\min(d(x,y),1)$, where $d$ is a metric that induces the topology. The correct concept in the general case is *total boundedness* together with *completeness*. A metric space is compact if and only if it is totally bounded and complete. In the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual metric, total boundedness is equivalent to boundedness; moreover the space is complete. But this is a property of the metric, not invariant under homeomorphisms.

Comment: hmm, ok :) thank you for the explanation ! it was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$]0,1]$ is *not compact*: e.g. the sequence $(1/n)_n$  doesn't have a convergent subsequence within $]0,1]$. The proof is correct.

This example shows, that in a general metric space, it is *not true* that

compact = bounded and closed.

Comment: Why can't I conclude from Heine-Borel Theorem that $]0,1]$ is compact in $]0,2[$ with subspace topology ?

Comment: How is Heine-Borel stated? The problem is that $]0,1]$ is *not closed* in $\Bbb R$ (though indeed closed in $]0,2[$).