# Premises of the extreme value theorem on “restricted” domains

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and let $S \subset D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to check whether $f$ on $S$ fulfills the premises of the extreme value theorem. Is it true that the following two statements are equivalent because “compactness is a topological property?”

- $S$ is closed and bounded in $D$.
- $S$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In other words, can I decide which of these two statements to check?

An example: Let $f: x \rightarrow \ln(1 - x^2)$, so the domain $D$ of $f$ is $(-1, 1)$. Let $S$ be $[0, 1)$. Then $S$ is closed in $D$ but not bounded, and $S$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ but not closed. Either way I conclude that the premises of the extreme value theorem are not fulfilled.

Any flaws with this?

Answer (score 1):

For $S\subset D\subset X$ with $D$ equipped with the subspace topology, the set $S$ is compact in $D$ iff $S$ is compact in $X$ (see [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376719/compactness-and-subspaces) and [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508080/compactness-in-subspaces?rq=1)). Then by the Heine-Borel theorem, you need to check whether $S$  is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (*and not of* $D$).

Comment: Thank you. So, $S$ is closed and bounded in $D \Leftrightarrow S$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not hold in general? Could you provide a counterexample?

Comment: It is your example. $S=[0,1)$ is closed in $D=(-1,1)$, but not in $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: Okay, but then again $S$ is not bounded in $D$ or is it?

Comment: $S$ is contained in $B(0,1)$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Metric_space

Comment: Thank you. German Wikipedia says that the ball needs to be closed, but I guess that’s a matter of definition